# Not able to use assembly plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using scala version 2.11.7

I want to build a jar file from sbt which can be executed on a machine where scala is not installed.

I guess i have to package the scala-library.jar in my jar file.

Based on some googling, I think I will have to use the assembly plugin of sbt

I added a new file called assembly.sbt to my project and added the following lines

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", 
url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")
```

but when I do a `sbt package` I get an error

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11) (/Users/foo/git/AvroCopyUtil/assembly.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:avrocopyutil_2.11:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
```

Comment: I think you want the `assembly` task, i.e., `$ sbt assembly`.

Comment: when I do `sbt assembly` I get error `[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]         ^`

Comment: The `assembly.sbt` goes int `project/` folder

Comment: You nailed it... that's the answer. could you please post your response as an answer so that I can mark it as such! thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `assembly.sbt` must go inside the `project/` folder.